# Insert outlook 2007 button within menu in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

In Outlook 2007 you have the navigation panel, consisting of "Mail","Calendar","Contacts","Tasks" etc (this is all below the tree structure).

1) Is it possible (and if so, how?) to insert another user-defined button between, say, "Mail" and "Calendar"?

2) Programatically, how could I minimise the main pane? So if I was in "Mail", the main pane would be "Inbox".

I have been using Add-in Express for customisation, but I dont believe it can do the above and could be a general .NET question.

Comment: have you attempted a google search ..?

Comment: @user1107474 - There are paid controls that function exactly like this control.  No, Microsoft has not release a control like this, although there is nothing special about it.

Comment: **Do not post exact duplicates of the same question**.  Doing so degrades the quality of the system and will more than likely draw flags on your questions, possibly prompting further moderator action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) You cannot create new [Navigation Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.navigationmodules%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in the [Navigation Pane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.navigationpane%28v=office.12%29.aspx). See MSDN forums for [related question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/e8359a5e-98f1-4bb3-b818-e3f72a7b52f5).

2.) An [Outlook View Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff871384.aspx) will let you takeover the currently active view pane.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean create an additional button inside Outlook, or reuse the button styles/etc in a 3rd party application?

If you mean inside Outlook, then yes, Outlook 2010 (not 2007) provides some OM hooks to add 1 additional button here. [It's called the Solutions module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692173.aspx). If there is only one solution installed, the name of the button takes the title of the solution. If there are multiple solutions then the title reverts to "Solutions"

If you mean outside of Outlook, then no. It's not possible. These buttons are not COM components (in fact, they're not even proper HWNDs).